# Including obscured IDs in the URL

Tags: php, mysql, url, encryption, hash

I need to include the user ID in the URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/user.php?id=123456
```

However, there is a problem. If a user manually changes the ID in the URL to `123455` for example, that could potentially lead to an erroneous update of the database.

For this reason, I need to somehow make the ID in the URL unreadable to the user so they can't just subtract 1 from the ID and be able to alter another user's data.

Another requirement is that the ID in the URL must be usable, meaning that whatever we do to it, PHP must have a way of figuring out the database row corresponding to that particular ID.

There are 2 possible solutions I can think of. I would be happy to hear your opinion on which one is better. If there's an even better solution that I haven't thought of, please let me know.

1. Including an encrypted version of the ID in the URL - that should make it extremely difficult for a user to just change the ID in the URL and guess another user's encrypted ID. It's also easy for PHP to decrypt the ID when needed and use it to request the user's data from the database.
2. Adding a new column called "hash" in the "users" table in the database. As you may have guessed, every user will have a unique random hash or UUID stored in the database which will be included in the URL. That makes guessing another user's hash very unlikely. PHP can easily retrieve the user's data by using the hash in the database query.

Comment: Obfuscation _never_ is a solution to a security issue.

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based, and is not a good fit for this site. I recommend: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @arkascha I wouldn't say never. Let's say you need to provide links publicly to users, and users with no access level should be able to view them. It would be beneficial to have a fairly obfuscated link so that they can't easily view others, but the person that should have access to the link, get's one that authenticates/allows them to view.

Comment: @FrankerZ What you sketch is _not_ an authentication scheme, but an attempt to keep out most users by obfuscation. That has _nothing_ to do with authentication or authorization. A public link that is self contained can _never_ be considered a protection. _It can simply be posted to a forum for example._

Comment: @arkascha If posted to a forum, users still wouldn't be able to find other links (It's on the user that gets the link to do what they want with it). Google uses this exact method for shareable links for google docs.

Comment: @FrankerZ your example is very close to the behavior I'm after. Now that I think about it, perhaps using hashes is the way to go, like the ones Google Drive, bit.ly and similar sites use.

Comment: @Jeff Just make sure you use hashes that are hard to guess. Don't simply use `md5(id)` or `sha256(id)`. Add a long salt onto the string, so that users cannot simply infer the hash, and backtrack it. ie. `sha256('thisIsAReallyLongStringWithNumb3ersAnd$pecial©haracters' . $id)`

Answer (score 2):

> If a user manually changes the ID in the URL to 123455 for example, that could potentially lead to an erroneous update of the database.

The way to solve this problem is to have sanity checks on the server so the user is not allowed to erroneously update the database. You either want some sort of permission checking ("this user is not allowed to update this record"), or other consistency checks that ensure no updates can be made erroneously ("the user is generally allowed to update this record, but right now it would cause a conflict with something else, so we won't").

You will have to include *some* id in the URL, and a user will always be able to change that id. At best you can make valid ids harder to guess by using something other than consecutive numbering, but that doesn't solve the underlying problem that your server has no sanity checks. Don't fault the user for generating errors, it's your code that's allowing it.

Comment: In almost all other cases it's possible to do sanity checks, but not in this one. Think bit.ly and similar sites. They have no way of doing any checks since they have to serve the content to whoever comes with a valid link. At the same time, they use hashes which makes guessing others' shortened links difficult. In the end, I decided to use random 24-character hex hashes that are stored in the database along with the ID. That's secure and convenient enough for my use case.

Comment: If there is no possible check you can enforce, then the definition of “erroneous” is vague at best. If the user is allowed to visit a particular link, then them visiting the link can’t be erroneous. You might not have expected them to visit that link, but you didn’t prevent it either. Yes, if you don’t want them to simply enumerate all possible links, a less predictable id like a long hex string will help a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I appreciate it. I guess you're right. "Unexpected" or "unwanted" is a better word choice than "erroneous".

Answer (score 1):

You should use sessions for this, not GET[] parameters, sessions are the tool for this Job. You can try the solutions you think of but from my point of view using sessions will be a lot better and simpler to use and implement.

But if you need to do something like the classic "recover my acount" so you don't have a way to log in you user, them you may use a hash in an URL and send it by email to "ensure" your user is the one who get's the URL.

Comment: It must be in the URL, I can't use sessions, and I can't send emails.